# Query rows using Order by A, if A values are the same, Order by B as the second standard

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to query db rows using two standards: A first, B second.
That is: Order by A, if A values are the same, Order by B as the second standard
How to write the sql?
Example:
query table:

```
id | A | B
_ _ _ _ _ _
1  | 1 | 1
_ _ _ _ _ _
2  | 2 | 2 
_ _ _ _ _ _
3  | 2 | 1
_ _ _ _ _ _
4  | 3 | 1
```

query result:

```
id
1
3
2
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by is used to sort the result from a table in ASC | DESC based on one or more column names. It sorts by ASC in default.

Example:

`Select * from Table1 order by A, B`

In this example the results from Table1 is sorted in ASC by A as well as B. If A has the same values, then the results will be sorted by B in ASC

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have multiple order-by's: `ORDER BY A DESC,B` for example.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result:

```
Select * from SomeTable ORDER BY A ASC, B ASC
```